# Svn block diff of certain file types

Tags: svn, diff

How do I tell svn not to diff certain file types when I type "svn diff"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the svn:mime-type of the file to it's correct value (or a value associated with binary data).  This will disable "svn diff" textual output and only print if the files differ.

Since it is version control, you are never going to get it to completely ignore if the files differ; because, you asked it if they differed, it tracks versions, and you included that file in the ones you are scanning.

The mime type for "a general bag of bytes" is application/octet-stream, but you might have a more appropriate setting if it's a jpeg file, etc.